# Mixing Full Page-Width Navbar With A 960px Body

Tags: navigation, layout, alignment, header

Is there ever a use case for mixing a full-width top navigation bar (meaning the navigation bar content is also full-width) with a contained body (around 960px)? What are the benefits or drawbacks to doing so in terms of usability and design?

IMO, it should either be full-width or contained, but not both because mixing would cause usability issues:

- Quick scan-ability isn't possible because of the difference in
  alignments.
- The disparity is especially bad on wider screens, forcing
  more eye and mouse movement to even use the navigation bar elements. This could minimize the effectiveness of the navigation bar.

Still, I'm interested in exploring the idea further. Are there any websites that have pulled this off successfully?

**Edit**

Here is an example mockup of what I'd like feedback on:

[image: mockup of top navigation bar and content 960px wide]

**Edit Redux**

Some examples have been given, but the heart of what I'm after is if this is a good idea and, if so, when it should be used. Even though Google does it, I'm not convinced that this is actually a user-friendly design pattern.

Comment: The only time I can recall seeing this mix is in those terrible `<iframe>` sharing topbars: it definitely makes the page look and feel disjointed.

Comment: This sounds like the beginning discussion of an iPad or other tablet UI. I would spend a few minutes browsing the Android, iOS, and Amazon Kindle marketplaces for some screenshots or examples.

Comment: It's actually not specifically for any mobile or tablet device. Just a normal website.

Comment: any examples? can't think of any site with full-width navbar *content* i.e. there are many with full-width navbar but its content would still be well-aligned

Comment: like http://www.google.com and http://37signals.com

Comment: brilliant question, really helpful!

Answer (score 7):

If you consider **Google** to be a **successful** company who have started to shape up on **User Experience** the last year, then that is your answer. They implement a full width top navigation bar on all of their sites, and some of the content is narrower and centered in the middle. It looks like the pattern in your question.

[image: Google full width navigation bar]

## [Google bar’s updated look](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1714464)

Posted on [Googles support site](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1714464) one can read:

> The Google bar is made up of two parts: A dark gray bar where you can click to access various Google services and a light gray bar to help you search, share, and manage your account. [...]
>
> The light gray bar may contain a search box for the Google service you are currently using. If you are a Google+ user, to the right you will see a share box and notifications icon to participate in Google+ from any Google page.

Google have had a lot of comments to remove the bar entirely and made a try in november last year (2011). But that design (a hover drop down menu) where even more refused by the community. [Google had to go back to the black bar again](http://www.searchengineshowdown.com/blog/2012/02/google_bar_goes_back_to_top_.shtml), but are [asking the community](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1714464) what to do instead.

From my own personal view I like the black bar since I always know where to find my Google services. The "community" isn't always right, but they make a lot of noice. I think it's safe to use the browser window wide navigation bar on the top - since users can always find what they need with only one click.

Comment: Do you know if Google has published anything on why they decided to go this route?

Comment: @VirtuosiMedia It's very hard to find the original idea of the bar, but I've made my best to edit the answer on what's going on at the moment. I hope it will be useful to you.

Comment: @VirtuosiMedia Jon Wiley presented it at UXweek, the video is available at http://uxweek.com/2011/videos/ That's the closest thing to a "rationale" that I am aware of.

Comment: What is interesting is that it does give a degree of separation between the bar and the content, which I suspect is deliberate. Google wants to be the portal for everything, not just a search engine provider. So they have the top bar indicating all of the things they do, and the trivial content of the actual process comes below - sometimes full width, sometimes not.

Comment: really good example, google have got this hierachy technique spot on

Answer (score 1):

I have used such stuff in some of the designs I have done.

In my opinion based on some of the research work done, both the things can be mixed if they don't have a direct relationship between the two.

Like in case of google, the content on top bar has no direct relationship between the content and the navigation on top. It can be termed as additional featured which doesn't effect even it removed.

I once designed a website where the user needed to login to access some of the content of a website. The website was already designed and I was working as a consultant to determine the drawback and give suggestion to some of the new featured introduced. My take on that was since the website layout remains the same and only the content of the site changes based on the login then it is better to use a dark top bar where we can list the user profile and edit option and keep the site below that. It actually acted like a toolbar which never interfered with the overall design of the site.

As for the alignment and scanning, since these are very rarely used option the user had no problem accessing them.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the [New York State Department of Labor](http://labor.ny.gov) uses a "full-width" persistent navigation bar for its persona based navigation (mega menu) at the top of the screen. Once you reach a more content specific area, an additional side bar appears to the left. The side bar then provides users with a form of content specific navigation.

Top Navigation

[image: Labor home page showing mega menu]

Side Navigation (Area in white denotes selected/current page)

[image: Labor page showing side navigation]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, JeffH, but this is actually an example of a navbar where its content is contained and not full-width. While the navbar itself is full-width, I'm looking for examples where the navbar content is also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check out an example play around with [Swipely](https://swipely.com) (you'll have to make an account to see the regular UI). I personally don't think it's a "bad" experience but not sure it adds much.

I can see a use case on a site a lot of text content where is may actually be beneficial. Content is contained within the body area and scrolls. Menu/buttons are pushed out to the sides to create a more "distraction free" reading environment. It's a stretch... but could be useful in some situations.

Comment: I only saw one page where it was mixed, the rest was either contained or full-width. I think that site has quite a number of usability issues, though, one of them being that they switch back and forth between full-width and contained content from page to page. Nothing is ever in the same place.